# Problem installing ICD3 windows driver

Tags: pic, programmer, development-tools

I recently had my ICD3 programmer stop working. I received a replacement today and before returning the old ICD3 wanted to test the new ICD3 out. I connected the new ICD3 to my PC and Windows XP Professional SP3 32-bit prompted me to install the drivers for the device. I selected the drivers located in the MPLAB IDE (v8.63) directory. When the installer reached the NcGen.sys file the computer hung up and I had to force the system to power down using the power button. Has anyone else had and resolved this issue with the Microchip ICD3?

Comment: Try contacting Microchip support. I've always found them very helpful.

Comment: You'd be better off on the Microchip specialist forum at http://www.microchip.com/forums/f49.aspx

Comment: I've been in touch with Microchip support. They haven't resolved the issue yet. I figured I'd check here to see if anyone has had similar problems with the ICD3.

Answer (score 2):

Boot up in Safe Mode, goto c:\windows\system32\driver and remove NcGen.sys
  Then connect the USB cable of ICD 3, install the driver then reboot your system. Now here you go!

Good Luck